# LWC Button does not close its modal window

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

The current code, has a Cancel button at bottom of modal. On Click, the modal disappears.

Current HTML

```
<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-right_xx-small" type="submit" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button>
```

JS

```
    handleCancel(event){
        this.rating = '0';
        this.cancel = true;
        this.handleSubmit(event);
    }

  handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.cancel == false && this.rating == 0){
            const err = new ShowToastEvent({
                "title": "Error",
                "message": "Please select a rating value before you submit",
                "variant": "error"
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(err);
        }
        if (this.cancel || (this.cancel == false && this.rating > 0)){
          const fields = event.detail.fields;
          fields.App_Name__c = this.appName;
          fields.Rating__c = this.rating.toString();
          fields.User__c = this.userId;
          fields[APP_TO_OBJECT.get(this.appName)] = this.recordId;
          this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
        }
    }
```

That works fine, but now I need to remove the Cancel button, and replace it with a close button (looks like an 'X') at Upper Right of the Modal Window. I thought I should be able to use the same JS, but the new button does nothing when I click it:

```
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <!--lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small slds-m-right_xx-small" type="submit" label="Cancel" onclick={handleCancel}></lightning-button-->
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close"
                   onclick={handleCancel}>
                   <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Close Modal" variant="inverse" size="small">
                   </lightning-icon>
                </button>
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">
                   Modal Header
                </h2>
             </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event` content that `handleCancel` forwards to `handleSubmit` will be different e.g. won't have a `fields` collection.

As you rely on the behaviour of the `<lightning-button type="submit" ...` button that is tied to the form it sits in, perhaps a separate function that programmatically clicks that button when the new Cancel button is clicked is needed. You can use e.g. `slds-hide` to make the `<lightning-button type="submit" ...` button invisible.